# What is the recommended way to delay non critical operations in a method?

Tags: .net, performance

I have the following piece of code:

```cs
public int Get5() {
   // Not critical for presentation operation
   LoggingService.Log();

   // Retrieve data. The data calculation operation is lightweight operation.
   return 5;
}
```

As you can see from the code most of the time the method takes is for logging. Since this operation is not critical I want to delay it and return data as soon as possible.

**Notes:**

- I can use Task.Run() but this will introduce overhead for changing the method context.
- I can use yeild return but I have to change the method signature.
- I can use a message queue mechanism but this will definitely be an overkill.

**So what is the recommended way to do this?** Is it worth it at all?

Comment: If logging is the bottleneck for your application and the last thing you need to optimize, then well, congratulations!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the easiest way is to get the logging framework that supports it. E.g. there is an [async wrapper](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target) for the NLog, which is a great logging framework.

Logging is usually happening very fast though and it is probably in some realtime applications where it makes sense to avoid (like exchange feeds or some hardware e.g.). Otherwise like in a case of ordinary web application, it would not matter at all and you should try to optimize other parts of your system before going to such low level. If we take web request/response as an example, then sending the data over the wire would be so much slower anyway, so that by optimizing logging you would get increase that is probably below 1% which is not noticeable.

P.S. I have never needed to optimize the logging away in such a manner during all my career so I think it's just not worth the time unless you really need it.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I'm looking for a general purpose solution for slow operations, that if possible doesn't involve additional/different threads.

Comment: I don't think it's quite possible to do without additional threads unless you put the log in some queue and then dequeue it later in the same thread on timer or some other event. But Why would you want to do it without involving another thread though? If you have one thread that handles the logging this way, then there is close to 0 cost per operation (just add data to some shared structure). And I suppose that's what logging frameworks do already.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably have a method for the non-critical operations and pass it to worker thread using async and await. This will make the main thread to delegate the operation to the worker thread. The operations are delegated to worker threads once await is encountered and the rest of the method will be handled by worker thread.

public async int Get5() {
   // critical operations
   await
   // any non- critical operations
}

Comment: Actually, await/async will block until the async operations are completed. Unfortunately it will make returning data to the user even slower than the example shown above because of working with additional threads(passing some context etc.)